# How to substract "hue" of an image from the original image using OPENCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to subtract the "hue" part of an image from that image.I have extracted all the h,s,v components .But i do not  know what to do next?Is it even possible??

Here is my code

```
import cv2

def showimage(text,img):
    cv2.imshow(text,cv2.resize(img, (700, 700)))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    return 0


# Read image in BGR
img_path = "new.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
showimage("orig",img)
# Convert BGR to HSV and parse HSV
hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
showimage("hsv",hsv_img)
h, s, v = hsv_img[:, :, 0], hsv_img[:, :, 1], hsv_img[:, :, 2]
showimage("h",h)
showimage("s",s)
showimage("v",v)

sub=hsv_img-h
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What do you mean by «subtract the "hue" part of an image»? Do you want a greyscale version of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant subtract `hsv_img` and `h` as they are of not same dimensions. However, you can subtract a grayscale version of the image with `h`. For that, add the lines  -

```
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
sub = gray_img-h
showimage("sub",sub)
```

However, if you are trying to visualize an image with zero hue component, you can do that with the code below -

Example:

[image] [image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def showimage(text,img):
    cv2.imshow(text,cv2.resize(img, (500,500)))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    return 0


# Read image in BGR
img_path = "new.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
showimage("orig",img)
# Convert BGR to HSV and parse HSV
hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
showimage("hsv",hsv_img)
h, s, v = hsv_img[:, :, 0], hsv_img[:, :, 1], hsv_img[:, :, 2]
showimage("h",h)
showimage("s",s)
showimage("v",v)

h = np.zeros_like(h)

img2 = cv2.merge((h,s,v))
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
showimage("With h=0 ", img2)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```